# How to link JDK to Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, java

Hi I am in trouble while creating a new project. I can't link the JDK to the IDE.

[image]

Here a my env variables related to java :

JAVA HOME : /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk

JAVA ROOT :  /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk

JAVA BINDIR :  /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin

What should I use ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directories with `jre` in the name are just runtime environments, and don't include the entire JDK. Choose one of the actual JDK directories like `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0`

EDIT: looking at your screenshot, it looks like you don't actually have JDK 1.8 installed, just the JRE (since the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0` only contains `jre`), so you'll need to install that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
I had to download the jdk here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Solved.